# Best way to scan your LAN network with Android

Tags: java, android, networking, service-discovery

I need to implement a "network scan" on my Android app. Basically, I need a list of all connected devices in my LAN, each with the respective information (device name, IP, MAC addresses).

I tried the Network Service Discovery libraries added to Android 4.1, following the official [documentation](http://developer.android.com/training/connect-devices-wirelessly/nsd.html) , but I don't know for what "Service name" I should start the discovery, so my list stays empty... I even tried to ping each IP in my subnet, and after that read my device's ARP cache, but even that does seem to behave randomly.

Any advice on the matter, please?

Answer (score -2):

I use FING - for Android, its free and provides all the stats you are looking for + more

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.overlook.android.fing&hl=en

Comment: Thanks, but that's just an example of what I'm trying to do by programming it by myself. Fing works great, by the way...